# TypeScript Error with object key which is number

Tags: typescript

I have the following object.

```
type Test = {
  0: number[];
  1: number[];
};
```

There will always be 2 keys named '0' and '1' in the object.

I want to iterate each key in the object and print the number in the value.

```
const logEveryItem = (test: Test): void => {
  for (let key in test) {
    test[key].forEach((i: number) => console.log(i));
  }
};
```

But `test[key]` from the 3rd line, TypeScript gives the following error.

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Test'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Test'.

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why there is an error ?**

Because `for .. in` operator, by the default, uses `string` type for iterable property.

```js
const logEveryItem = (test: Test): void => {
    // let prop: string
    for (let prop in test) {

    }
};
```

`string` type is to wide for `test` keys. For instance, you are not allowed to use `test['any string']` to access a property. IN this case `prop` should be `0 | 1`. TypeScript does not infer it as `0 | 1` be the default because how `in` operator works.
See this example:

```js
type Test = {
    0: number[];
    1: number[];
};

class SuperTest {
    foo = 'hello'
}

class SubTest extends SuperTest {
    0: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
    1: number[] = [4, 5, 6]
}

const logEveryItem = (test: Test): void => {
    // let prop: string
    for (let prop in test) {
        console.log(prop)
        test[prop].forEach() // run time error
    }
};

logEveryItem(new SubTest())
```

Somebody could expect that it will log "0" and "1", but it will also log "foo". Please see [`for .. in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) docs.

> ... including inherited enumerable properties.

So, now we know that it is not safe to assume that we will only iterate through `0 | 1`. This is why `prop` infers as a `string`.

If you are interested in object values, I think it worth using `Object.values`:

```js
const logEveryItem2 = (test: Test): void => {
    Object.values(test)
        .forEach(elem => {
            console.log(elem)
        })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You either want a record:

```
type Test = Record<string, number[]> // or Record<number, number[]> if you want your key to be a number.
```

which is the same as :

```
type Test = {
  [key: string]: number[]
};
```

or a tuple

```
type Test = [number[], number[]] // could be of the length you want.
```

Comment: Tuple / Record depends on how he wants to call logEveryItem. 
Tuple: logEveryItem([[0,1],[2,3]])
Record: logEveryItem({"0":[0,1],"1": [2,3]});

Comment: In his example, the key is a number.

Answer (score -1):

The type should be:

```
type Test = {
  [key: string]: number[]
};
```